# How to store unique index for each and every Treenode in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have created one TreeView in asp.net.I want to store unique index for each and every treenode created in the TreeView.I am using ValuePath.But it may be duplicate case.

So, Please Guide me to store unique index for each and every tree node...

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a unique value for each Treenode, then you can use `GUID` class to generate a new one using `Guid.NewGuid()` method. Use the generated `GUID` as and where you like.

Comment: :ok How to relate this GUID with each and every Tree Node?

Comment: Assign it to `TreeNode.Value` property.

Comment: :each time when pressing tree node then selectegNodeChanged event triggered and page is reloaded.So, i lost some data stored in list.How to prevent those data losing? Please Help me...

Comment: This problem should be reported as a separate question. Please accept answer if it resolved your original question.